# How do I prevent dns rebinding attacks on my development machines?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, security, dns

I use my Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 notebooks for development purposes and regularily run various servers (e.g. web servers) on a network address not otherwise accessible from the internet.

How do I avoid still exposing such servers to the world via my web browsers, in case someone rebinds his domain name to a private IP?

The attack is further described in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu defaults to `dnsmasq` as a caching DNS server.

You can check if you are affected (some dns servers have such protection enabled by default, so *via your current connection* you might already be safe)

```
$ dig +short 2.0.0.127.zen.spamhaus.org
127.0.0.10
```

Installing *dnsmasq* will automatically setup your /etc/resolv.conf to point all name resolution to the local dnsmasq instance.

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

The option to reject private IPs from upstream servers can easily be added:

```
echo "stop-dns-debind" | sudo tee /etc/dnsmasq.d/stop-rebinding
```

Do not forget to restart the DNS server after changing options:

```
sudo restart dnsmasq
```

Test configuration as above, no 127.0.0.0/8 answer should be returned.

Refer to the dnsmasq manual in case your machine for any reason actually needs to query RBLs (such as the one referred in the test above) - partial exemptions from the protection are possible.